# Kivy Scrollview in kv language - id not defined

Tags: scrollview, kivy, kivy-language

Trying to figure out how to implement a straight-forward ScrollView in KV language based on the examples given in the documentation. I cannot believe I cannot find a single example of this (only parts of solution), so I thought it would be easy. Turns out it's not.

My issue is that I need to populate my scrollable grid layout with a list of labels from within the kivy script, using add_widget. That's because I have a variable number of of labels to add (although that number is fixed in the below example to make things simple). However the program wouldn't let me do it, saying that the ID I defined for the grid layout object is not defined. Therefore I am not able to add the labels to the grid layout.

```
NameError: name '_gridlayout' is not defined
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        size_hint: 1, .2
        Label:
            text: "Random text"
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        size_hint: 1, .8
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id: _gridlayout
                cols: 1
                padding: 10
                spacing: 10
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 500           
''')

class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.buildList()
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def buildList(self):
        for i in range(30):
            btn = Label(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            _gridlayout.add_widget(btn)   # <- ERROR

class SMApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SMApp().run()
```

UPDATE: Corrected script below.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        size_hint: 1, .2
        Label:
            text: "Random text"
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        size_hint: 1, .8
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id: _gridlayout
                cols: 1
                padding: 10
                spacing: 10
                size_hint_y: None
                width: 500           
''')

class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.buildList()        

    def buildList(self):
        for i in range(30):
            btn = Label(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            self.ids._gridlayout.add_widget(btn)
        self.ids._gridlayout.bind(minimum_height=self.ids._gridlayout.setter('height'))


class SMApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SMApp().run()
```

Comment: Well... I figured out I needed to use "self.ids._grid_layout". Makes the app crash, though (AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__')  but I think the method is correct.

Comment: In `__init__` try first the super call (`super([...]).__init__(**kwargs)`, maybe kivy widget first needs to do some magic before you can add widgets. Next time please add the complete traceback.

Comment: Yes that was it, plus the missing binding to enable the scrolling. Thanks a lot. I´ll keep in mind posting the full traceback next time, sorry about that.
I´ll go ahead and update my OP with the corrected script.

Comment: @OmarLittle You should post the correct answer in a separate post, and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy is very picky about calling `Widget.__init__()` first. So if you overwrite `__init__` of a widget be sure to first call `super().__init__`, otherwise you can get errors like you encountered or "random" crashes.

To fix change

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.buildList()
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

to

```
class MainScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.buildList()
```